# In this question i am not getting how the case of (Some roads being boards is a possibility) is false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question: All papers are clips. Some clips are boards. Some boards are lanes. All lanes are roads.
When i tried it using Venn Diagram minimum possibility method. I came to know that the above case is true. But i am following one book that says its false.
(In case of possibility).

Please help me out. See the image what i tried to solve this.
[Venn Diagram Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdWo6.png)

Comment: Your Venn diagram seems to match the conditions. What is your question?

Comment: My question is that if statement case is (Some) and required possibility case is also in (Some) than what would be the result?

http://www.completesuccess.in/reasoning/syllogism please visit this link and see Question No 48 and 50.

Comment: Your book says *what* is false?  The statements are laying conditions but not stating any conclusions.

Comment: Your venn diagram has lanes and roads completely distinct from papers and clips.  You diagram is *possible* but it isn't necessarily true.  Yours isn't minimum either.  As lanes and roads *could* be entirely in clips.  So your diagram is neither minimal or maximum.

Comment: The notes say "None of this" because the listed possible answers do not include : Only **I**."Some roads are boards".

Comment: You don't list any conclussions.  We can't tell you if the conclusion is true or false if we don't know what the conclusion is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some boards are lanes.  Hence there is some object $x$, that is both a board and a lane.  All lanes are roads.  Since $x$ is a lane, $x$ is also a road.  Now, there is an object $x$ that is both a board and a road.  Hence some roads are boards.

Unless your book uses some strange meaning for the word "some", it is true that some roads are boards.

Comment: But their is a book of Arihant's publication that i am following and it says this is false. According to it if there is a case of (some -> some) relation with possibility than it always remains false.

Answer (score 1):

[Roads and Boards Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4IAO.jpg)
According to my diagram I also show that boards and roads are not exclusive.  Unless you have omitted or altered the question in some way, I would say it is a typo some where.

Answer (score 0):

In your venn diagram the boards clips and lanes should form a regular venn diagram on three circles, i.e. boards and lanes are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: completesuccess.in/reasoning/syllogism please visit this link and see Question No 48 and 50

Comment: Don't you mean question 20.